# How to make nodes in a chart focus traversable?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm on javafx-8 and java8, trying to make an interactive chart.

So far I've implemented all the mouse actions (highlight on mouse over, drag&drop to change values etc), but I'm not able to implement any keyboard interactions (basically changing its value with arrow keys) because the nodes (i.e. pic below) in a chart cannot gain focus.

[image]

When I try to set the focusTraversable property is fails with exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: StackPane.focusTraversable : A bound value cannot be set.
```

I have tried setting it on the chart but it doesn't get propagated to the data points (nodes). Can someone please point me the right way? thanks!

Comment: The exception says you have already bound the focusTraversableProperty, and therefor you cannot set it manuall using .setFocusTraversable(true); anymore

Comment: thanks, I understand that it is bound but I cannot find the variable it is bound to. I tried setting focusTraversable on the chart the node belong to but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

The binding of the symbol's focusTraversal is used in accessibility - the snippet from `LineChart.createSymbol(..)`:

```
symbol.focusTraversableProperty().bind(Platform.accessibilityActiveProperty());
```

As long as you can live without following accessibility constraints, you might get away (untested for side-effects!) by simply unbinding before setting it to true, something like:

```
Node node = data.getNode();
node.focusTraversableProperty().unbind();
node.setFocusTraversable(true);
```